# Check if object is instance of any 'number' class?

Tags: java

```
Object o = ?
if ((o instanceof Integer) || (o instanceof Double) || (o instanceof Float)|| (o instanceof Long))
```

Is there a shorter version to check if an Object is any of the Number types?

Comment: "Is there a shorter version to check if an Object is any of the Number types" - You asked the answer :) `instanceof Number`

Comment: Visit the [`Number API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), see its subclasses to understand why it works.

Comment: Yeah, I should have checked if they have a common superclass. 
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do

```
if (o instanceof Number) {
    Number num = (Number) o;
```

If you only have the class you can do

```
Class clazz = o.getClass();
if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
```

Note: this treats `Byte`, `Short`, `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` as numbers.

If you look at the [Javadoc for Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) you can see its parent is [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) which in turn has the sub-classes `AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, DoubleAccumulator, DoubleAdder, Float, Integer, Long, LongAccumulator, LongAdder, Short` so `instance Number` will match any of these.

Comment: `clazz` is clazzic name for class.